# jquery adding one parameter to newseltter form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to add one more parameter to the form and to check if it is valid or not but I am unable to do it properly...

Original:

```
newsletterForm: {
        selector: '#newsletter-form',
        init: function() {
            var base = this,
                    container = $(base.selector),
                    url = container.data('target');

            container.submit(function() {
                container.find('.result').load(url, {email: $('#email').val()},
                function() {
                    $(this).fadeIn(200).delay(3000).fadeOut(200);
                });
                return false;
            });

        }
    }
```

I was able to add a field in html but I am not able to add it here, here is what I tried:

```
newsletterForm: {
        selector: '#newsletter-form',
        init: function() {
            var base = this,
                    container = $(base.selector),
                    url = container.data('target');

            container.submit(function() {
                container.find('.result').load(url, {email: $('#email').val()}, {name: $('#name').val()},
                function() {
                    $(this).fadeIn(200).delay(3000).fadeOut(200);
                });
                return false;
            });

        }
    },
```

Not sure how to proceed here but I have in php file the following:

```
if (is_email($email){ // do something}
else{
  echo '<div class="notification-box error">';
  echo "Please enter a valid email address";
  echo "</div>";
}
```

Which is showed on page if email is not valid, but when I add it for name like

```
if (is_string($name){ // do something}
else{
  echo '<div class="notification-box error">';
  echo "Please enter a name";
  echo "</div>";
}
```

If I don't enter name when filling the form, it won't show this message on page.

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

EDIT:

```
$name = strtolower($_POST['name']);
$email = strtolower($_POST['email']);


if(!is_string($name) || empty($name)){
    echo '<div class="notification-box error">';
    echo "Please enter name";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would add another parameter to your existing call to`.load()`

```
container.find('.result').load(url, {
                                     email: $('#email').val(), 
                                     name: $('#name').val()
                                    },
```

You will need to add a bit more of your PHP code for me to be able to check that as well but `.load()` when passing an object like you are will use `POST` so you should be looking at

```
$_POST['name']
```

for the value of the data you are passsing in that parameter

EDIT:

You should really test for EMPTY before doing anything else. Also there is no need to move data from `$_POST` to scalar variables. Once PHP creates `$POST` for you , its all yours

```
if (!empty($_POST['email']) && is_email($_POST['email']){ 
  // do something}
else{
  echo '<div class="notification-box error">';
  echo "Please enter a valid email address";
  echo "</div>";
}

if(empty($_POST['name']) || !is_string($_POST['name']) ){
    echo '<div class="notification-box error">';
    echo "Please enter name";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: Yes I have it like `$name = strtolower($_POST['name']);` and I tried adding it like you described above but still I don't get any error message regarding name...

Comment: I don't get anything on page... and If I don't enter valid email I get "Please enter valid email"

Comment: SHow how you get the `name` out of $_POST into a variable?

Comment: You should be checking `isset($_POST_['email']])` and `isset($_POST(['name'])` Show more of your PHP code

Comment: Please check my question I added part of the code... Not sure how for email works and for name it doesn't...